# Desktop vs Laptop Performance for Software Development

Tags: laptop, processor, desktop

I have a Asus M32AD desktop tower pc, and a friend of mine selling Lenova Yoga 500 laptop. And I am going to buy it if laptop is suitable.

I am using my pc for developing mobile apps. With Android Studio, Visual Studio Code, etc... And I found Yoga 500 similar to my computer.

So my pc specs: i5 4460 @3.20gHz quad core cpu 12 gb ram nvidia gt740 gpu

Yoga 500 specs: i5 6200u @2.30 gHz dual core cpu 4 gb ram nvidia gt940m gpu

My idea is, I will buy Yoga 500 from my friend and add a 4gb ram, 256gb ssd.

What is your ideas? 
Is Yoga 500 will have a similar performance to my desktop pc?

I am really confused with laptop and desktop cpu's :(

Comment: You can objectively compare average expected performance with [benchmarks](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-4460-vs-Intel-Core-i5-6200U/2310vsm36796).

Answer (score 2):

## The laptop will be about 60-70% of the speed, spec-for-spec

The i5-4460 has a Passmark of 6728 (1942 single core), while the i5-6200 sports a Passmark of 4010 (1496 single core.) The GT 740 sports a Passmark of 1569, while the GT 940M supports a Passmark of 1007.  If you're happy developing on your desktop, this laptop should do okay, though it will be slightly slower.

That said, the real question is if this is a good deal for you. What do you want in a laptop: battery life, screen size, thin and light vs. larger, operating system, budget? Finally, what price are you getting it for?

Comment: Thank you for your point of view :) I clearly understood it now. I want to work in different places not at only my home. I am going to buy laptop $130 ~ 800 Turkish Liras.

Comment: That's a pretty solid deal, I'd take that if it works for you.